# операторы сравнения js

Tags: javascript

есть переменная

```
var drag1 = document.getElementById('drag1');
```

у нее вычисляется угол поворота

```
drag1._gsTransform.rotation;
```

вопрос первый как записывать

```
angle = drag1._gsTransform.rotation;
```

или

```
var angle = drag1._gsTransform.rotation;
```

вопрос 2:

нужно сравнить полученное значение угла.

к примеру, если угол между 0 и 30 - то...

как записать?

вот это не работает у меня

```
if (0 < drag1._gsTransform.rotation > 30) 
{....
```

и подставляя переменную angle тоже не работает.

как это все можно изобразить?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> как записывать
>
> ```
> angle = drag1._gsTransform.rotation;
> ```
>
> или
>
> ```
> var angle = drag1._gsTransform.rotation;
> ```

Если `angle` объявлена ранее, то первый вариант. А если не объявлена, то второй.
<sub>*Присваивание необъявленной переменной может работать как ожидается, но это чревато возможными ошибками и непредсказуемым поведением. Поэтому, переменные всегда лучше объявлять (однократно, конечно же).*</sub>

---

> к примеру, если угол между 0 и 30 - то...
>   как записать?

Именно *между* данными значениями:

```
if (angle > 0 && angle < 30)
```

или, если с 0 и 30 включительно:

```
if (angle >= 0 && angle <= 30)
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!